# Two ways to read hdfs sequece file, but one failed with EOFException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequencefile

Use sparkContext to read sequence file, as follows:

Method 1:

```
val rdd = sc.sequenceFile(path, classOf[BytesWritable], 
          classOf[BytesWritable])
rdd.count()
```

Method 2:

```
val rdd = sc.hadoopFile(path,
          classOf[SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat],
          classOf[BytesWritable],
          classOf[BytesWritable])
rdd.count()
```

Method 1 end up with EOFException, but method 2 works. What's the differences of these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference starts where "Method 1" immediately makes the call `hadoopFile(path, inputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass, minPartitions)` which uses `SequenceFileInputFormat[BytesWritable, BytesWritable]`, but "Method 2" makes the same call except of course uses `SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat`.
Then to continue, even though `SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat` extends `SequenceFileInputFormat[BytesWritable, BytesWritable]`,  `SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat` has it's own inner class called `SequenceFileAsBinaryRecordReader` and although it works similarly to `SequenceFileRecordReader[BytesWritable, BytesWritable]`, there are differences.  When we take a look at the code, they are doing some different implementations, namely the former is handling compression better.  So if your sequence file is either record compressed or block compressed then it makes sense that `SequenceFileInputFormat[BytesWritable, BytesWritable]` is not iterating with the same dependability as `SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat`.

`SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat` which uses `SequenceFileAsBinaryRecordReader` (lines 102-115)  - https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/a55d6bba71c81c1c4e9d8cd11f55c78f10a548b0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileAsBinaryInputFormat.java

`SequenceFileRecordReader` (lines 79 - 91)  - 
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/a55d6bba71c81c1c4e9d8cd11f55c78f10a548b0/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileRecordReader.java